# st_crop() follow latitudinal circle on polar projection

Tags: coordinate-system, r, clip, sf

I am generating a polar projection with the `rnaturalearth::ne_countries()` dataset. Because I'm only interested in high-latitude regions, I want to crop the shape above a particular latitude. However, when I crop, transform, and plot, the southernmost extent of each country that remains in the dataset does not follow latitudinal curves, because only two points represent the southern bounds of the data. For example, the US west coast and east coasts are connected by a straight line, as highlighted in the image below (red rectangle added manually). Ideally, I want the southern "borders" of countries that were cut in half to follow the thin blue dotted line (added manually).

[image: boundaryProblem]

How can I get a latitudinal crop + transform to follow curves? Spatial* or sf* solutions are both welcome.

Reproducible example:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

countries = rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf") %>%
  st_crop(y = st_bbox(c(xmin = -180, ymin = 35, xmax = 180, ymax = 90)))
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = countries)

countries2 = st_transform(countries,
             crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=sphere +units=m +no_defs"))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = countries2)
```

Comment: Maybe you could densify your polygons before transforming? So that by having vertices close together, the reprojection will transform all those vertices and give you a much smoother result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per FSimardGIS's suggestion, I added a call to `densify()` in my initial pipeline:

```
countries = rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf") %>%
  st_crop(y = st_bbox(c(xmin = -180, ymin = 35, xmax = 180, ymax = 90))) %>%
  smoothr::densify(max_distance = 1) %>%
  st_transform(crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=sphere +units=m +no_defs"))
```

This generated an acceptable approximation of the curve for my purposes:
[image: approxCurve]