# Making a cosmetic mask for an Arctic projection in R using sf

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf

I'm making a fairly detailed map of the northern high latitudes that I want to show with an Arctic projection. I'd like to have a map that has a transparent circle from 50N to 90N as a mask for the final image. Seems easy. But I'm stuck. What I'd like is for the map in `p1` below to be reprojected into North Pole Azimuthal Equidistant projection with the data below 50N to be greyed out and the data above 50N to show through. Any tips?

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

#get coastlines as a demo
coastlines <- rnaturalearth::ne_coastline(scale = 50, returnclass = "sf") 
st_crs(coastlines) <- "EPSG:4326"

# create arctic(ish)  bounding box
arcticBox <- data.frame(id="A",
                        lon = c(-180,180,180,-180,-180),
                        lat = c(90,90,50,50,90))

otherBox <- data.frame(id="B",
                       lon = c(-180,180,180,-180,-180),
                       lat = c(50,50,-90,-90,50))

boxes <- bind_rows(arcticBox,otherBox)

boxesSF <- st_as_sf(boxes,coords=c("lon","lat"),crs="EPSG:4326") %>%
  group_by(id) %>% summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") 

p1 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data=coastlines,color="blue",size=0.25) +
  geom_sf(data=boxesSF,mapping = aes(fill=id),color=NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=alpha(colour=c("blue", "grey"), 
                                 alpha = c(0,1))) +
  coord_sf(ylim = c(0,90)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

p1
```

[image]

```
p1 + coord_sf(crs = sf::st_crs("ESRI:102016"))
```

[image]

Where did the masking polygons go? Something weird with having -180 to 180 meeting?

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376019/st-crop-follow-latitudinal-circle-on-polar-projection?rq=1) which provided the solution. You first need to densify your polygon as it currently only contains 4 vertices (the corners) and therefore doesn't follow the curve of the parallels when reprojecting. The `densify` function from the `smoothr` package should do the trick (also please remember to include relevant packages in your reproducible example: `ggplot2` and `rnaturalearth` were missing).

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)
library(smoothr)

#get coastlines as a demo
coastlines <- rnaturalearth::ne_coastline(scale = 50, returnclass = "sf") 
st_crs(coastlines) <- "EPSG:4326"

# create arctic(ish)  bounding box
arcticBox <- data.frame(id="A",
                        lon = c(-180,180,180,-180,-180),
                        lat = c(90,90,50,50,90))

otherBox <- data.frame(id="B",
                       lon = c(-180,180,180,-180,-180),
                       lat = c(50,50,-90,-90,50))

boxes <- bind_rows(arcticBox,otherBox)

boxesSF <- st_as_sf(boxes,coords=c("lon","lat"),crs="EPSG:4326") %>%
  group_by(id) %>% summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>% 
  smoothr::densify(max_distance = 1)  ## densify your polygon

p1 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data=coastlines,color="blue",size=0.25) +
  geom_sf(data=boxesSF,mapping = aes(fill=id),color=NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=alpha(colour=c("blue", "grey"), 
                                 alpha = c(0,1))) +
  coord_sf(ylim = c(0,90)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

p1 + coord_sf(crs = sf::st_crs("ESRI:102016"))
```

[image: arctic-circle]